# Merge multiple SQL queries for efficiency

Tags: mysql, sql

How would I combine these two SQL queries into a single query for greater speed and efficiency?

```
SELECT price FROM table LIMIT 30
SELECT AVG(price) as avg FROM table
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to optimize here...  Are the queries running slow, or are you just trying to do some premature micro-optimization?

Comment: How would you suggest "combining" them?  One is a list of prices and the other is an average of those prices.  How do you want this information grouped or displayed?

Comment: @Siyual I have about 20 million rows of data and want everything to be as fast as possible

Comment: @Dresden That is basically the crux of the problem. I want to know whether or not this is possible, because as you say, one is a list and the other is a single item. Ultimately, I want to echo out both using PHP and display the results on a page.

Comment: The average query has to read the entire table.  The first query selects 30 arbitrary rows.  The average will dominate the results no matter what you do.

Comment: 20 million rows isn't exactly a lot of data.  Try putting an index on `price` if there isn't one already.  It doesn't make any sense combining these two queries into one.  The first query is only randomly pulling 30 prices (with no ordering at all), and the second is pulling the average *of all 20,000,000* prices.

Answer (score 0):

It will not be faster or more efficient, but I can see needs for it (such as trying to compare a value to the average), something like this:

```
SELECT t.value, avgSubQ.theAvg, t.value / avgSubQ.theAvg AS relativeToAvg
FROM table AS t
INNER JOIN (SELECT AVG(value) AS theAvg FROM table) AS avgSubQ
LIMIT 30;
```

Answer (score 0):

as avg will generate 1 record, you could just use a cross join.

```
SELECT price, B.mavg 
FROM table 
CROSS JOIN (SELECT AVG(price) as mavg FROM table) B
LIMIT 30
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query
**SELECT price,avg(price) as avg from table LIMIT 30**

Here every row will duplicate the average price, but you'll get what you want in one query.

Comment: Actually, you will just get one random price; the results will be a single row every time.

Comment: try this : select price,avgs from table ,(select avg(price) as avgs from table) as tx;